# ASP.NET cookies not persiting if VisualBasic web app is restarted in VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

If I run my web app in VisualStudio, and set cookies, they aren't there if I end the web app and run it again.

Here are my cookie set and get functions:

( Is "userInfo" special or arbitrary? )

```
' Sets cookie cookie_name to cookie_value.
sub set_cookie( cookie_value , cookie_name  )
    response.Cookies( "userInfo" )( cookie_name ) = cookie_value 
    response.Cookies( SOFTWARE_PROGRAM_NAME).Expires = datetime.now.adddays(365*10)
end sub


' Returns cookie named cookie_name.
function get_cookie( byval cookie_name as string ) 
    If  Request.Cookies("userInfo") Is Nothing Then
        return ""
    else
        cookie_value =  Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies( "userInfo" )( cookie_name ))
        return   cookie_value
    end if
end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're effectively killing the web server.  This is going to wipe all variables from memory including cookies.

Try deploying it to IIS.